# Installed Ubuntu over Debian, But Only Debian boots

Tags: boot

I Installed Debian 8 and took a quick look at it. Then I installed Ubuntu 14 to have a look at it.
I am sure both operating systems are there, but the system boots into Debian. I have never seen Ubuntu desktop yet. I am sure I told it to cover Debian, but it looks like that didn't happen.
Is it to late to fix this mess?
I am a raw newbie, but one who has DOS, OS/9, and OS/2 Warp command line experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

looks like the grub didn't install... (or if it did it isn't working properly). easiest thing to do would be to put your ubuntu live disk/usb back in and fix that. there is a detailed explanation of what to do to re-install grub here: 
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd. 
Good luck! and hope you can get that working.